# At sign in bitbucket REAME files (and maybe more)

Tags: annotations, bitbucket, readme

I have written Java code that I'm maintaining using a Bitbucket repository. Now, while writing my README and describing some Java annotations, i.e.,

```
@Annotation
```

…the README markdown file interprets these as links to other users, which is very frustrating. As inline HTML seems to be not supported (I've tried "&#64;" = @), does anyone have a way of writing literal at signs in these README files?